# dragdrop save div/img position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I am currently using this sort of method, which lets me drag and drop divs/imgs within a div (perimeter based)

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    $("#video").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
    $("#umbrella").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
            $("#plane").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
            $("#peace").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
            $("#thought").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
    $("#thought2").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
    $("#beachball").draggable({ containment: "#container2", scroll: false });
});
</script>
```

I am trying to save the drag and drop of the DIV exactly where placed within the parimiter div and send it into a MYSQL table which will tell the browser where it should be placed in future (or after saving)

I'm just unsure how to get the exact co-ordinates via JS or JQUERY

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#video" ).draggable({
           stop : function () {
               alert("X=" + $(this).position().left + ", Y=" + $(this).position().top);
           } 
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/FXwME/

More info can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: For me its working. Have you tried the changes I suggested in your code, did it work there?

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question so no, I haven't tried the changes. I tried adding the jQuery and jQuery UI on the sidebar on jsFiddle and now the demo worked.

Comment: What URL are you talking about?

Comment: replace the demo url in my answer with yours.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```
var divPos = $('#div').position();
```

Now you can use

```
divPos.left
```

```
divPos.right
```

```
divPos.top
```

and

```
divPos.bottom
```

to get the exact co-ordinates.

For more information about .position(), look here: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: going to try the above out :D